# How to optimize JavaScript closure memory usage?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, closures

I have nested callback functions as follows:

```
func1(a, function(b){
  var aa;
  func2(c, function(d){
    var cc;
    func3(e, function(f){
      var ee;
      // setup event handler responding to the message
      process.on('message',function(){
        var g = b;
      });
    });
  });
});
```

local variable 'g' references top-level closure parameter 'b'.

In this case,

- all the closure variables & parameters (aa,cc,ee,a,b,c,d,e,f) are kept in the memory?
- or only top-level closure variables & parameters (aa,a,b) are kept?

How about following code to keep the value of only 'b' instead of keeping all the closure environment variables like above code?

```
var global_b;
func1(a, function(b){
  global_b = b;
  b = null; // free the parameter 'b'
  func2(c, function(d){
    func3(e, function(f){
      // setup event handler responding to the message
      process.on('message',function(){
        var g = global_b;
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance for your opinions!

Comment: You should be able to find out what is being kept by breaking inside each function and looking at the "locals" (all F12 dev tools have that, showing you IIRC what vars are currently in scope). You also could un-nest the functions, *not* use globals and pass values around as parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Yes, I'd rather pass values around as parameters instead of using global vars :)